# Where mimeopen saves default app config?

Tags: openbox, mime-types, freedesktop, file-opening

I associated pdf with Okular using mimeopen. Then I became curious where it had saved the configuration. My first guess was:

$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list

but it didn't contain the right entry. So I searched:

```
updatedb && locate mime | xargs egrep -e "okular" 2> /dev/null
```

and found nothing. So which file is used mimeopen to save associations?

**update**

I started digging, following a clue from cas's comment, and I found a file:

$HOME/.local/share/okular-usercreated-1.desktop.

with the content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=okular
NoDisplay=true
Exec=okular
```

Which strangely does not have a *MimeType* record

**My guess:**
Since I use openbox, which doesn't set $DE environmental variable mimeopen had been forced to create a new .desktop file when I used it. Which is inconvenient.

I read it is possible to run openbox inside other desktop environments. I will give  it a try.

Comment: possibly `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`.  BTW, see man pages for `mimeopen`,`update-mime-database`, and `update-desktop-database`.   See also man pages for `xdg-open` and `xdg-mime` and related programs.  The freedesktop.org people have been busy little beavers making things as confusing and complicated as possible.

Comment: @cas Thanks you gave me a good direction to look

Comment: If you end up finding an answer, please write it up and post it, then Accept your own answer.  If it's a good answer, i'll upvote it (ping me with @cas in a comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found the records:**

mimeopen when no desktop environment is specified saves the records in:

*$HOME/.local/share/applications/defaults.list*

Comment: This isn't the location that `xdg-open` uses though!! Symlink it to `~/.config/mimeapps.list` for the win.